# VBScript Compilation Error Expected Statement with Excel sort object

Tags: excel, vbscript, syntax-error, vba

When I try to execute my VBScript using this line of code (which is taken from Microsoft's own docs) I get the following error:

> ```
> Microsoft VBScript compilation error Expected statement
> IActiveScriptSite::OnScriptError()
> Line:              .SortFields.add Key:=Range("E2:E11"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
> ```

Here is the code:

```
 With xlWorkSheet.Sort 
            .SortFields.Clear 
            .SortFields.Add Key:=Range("E2:E11"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal 
            .SetRange Range("A2:A11")
            .Header = xlYes 
            .MatchCase = False 
            .Orientation = xlTopToBottom 
            .SortMethod = xlPinYin 
            .Apply 
        End With
```

Taken from [Microsofts docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/sort-object-excel)

After incorporating suggestions from Rory, the following code is now throwing a runtime error "invalid procedure call or argument"

```
 With xlWorkSheet.Sort 
        .SortFields.Clear 
        .SortFields.Add xlWorkSheet.Range("E2:E10"), 0, 1, ,0 
        .SetRange xlWorkSheet.Range("A2:A10")
        .Header = 2 
        .MatchCase = False 
        .Orientation = 0 
        .SortMethod = 0 
        .Apply 
    End With
```

Comment: There is a quote missing in `Range("E2:E11)` it should be `Range("E2:E11")`. Same here `Range("A2:A11)` which should be `Range("A2:A11")`.

Comment: Your range is not terminated with double quote ! "E2:E11"

Comment: You are right! I should have proof read my question better, but that wasn't the fix. I had typed it out with that mistake. Fixing the double quote doesn't change the error I am getting.

Comment: did you try to specify a sheet for both ranges? Like `xlWorkSheet.Range("E2:E11")`?

Comment: @Pᴇʜ Just tried it..same error

Comment: This sounds like a combination of  basic syntax errors "read the documentation" problems

Comment: @dbmitch It definitely was. Grateful for the help. I was reading the docs but I didn't understand some of the issues.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

VBScript doesn't have named arguments. You have to specify them by position and remove the named parts.

```
.SortFields.Add xlworksheet.Range("E2:E11"), xlSortOnValues, xlAscending, , xlSortNormal
```

I'm assuming you have declared the constants somewhere. If not, either do so, or use the literal values:

```
.SortFields.Add xlworksheet.Range("E2:E11"), 0, 1, , 0
```

Note that you have to leave the gap for the missing `DataOption` argument that you aren't providing.

Comment: Sorry for my ignorance...could you explain a little more?

Comment: @daveMac Rory is referring to arguments such as `xlSortOnValues` which will be available in Excel environment but will not be when running through `vbscript`. Check for appropriate `Enum` and test your code.

Comment: @daveMac I've edited the answer to be more explicit.

Comment: Makes good sense. Now I am getting a runtime error "Variable is undefined: 'Range'

Comment: @daveMac Updated again - you were missing a worksheet qualifier there.

Comment: @Rory Thought of that...changed my code accordingly. Now I get a mysterious "VBScript runtime error Invalid procedure call or argument"

Comment: Have you replaced any other Excel constants with literals (`xlyes` and `xlpinyin` for example)?

Comment: `xlYes` and `xlPinYin` both have value 1, not what you have put in your code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172422/discussion-between-davemac-and-rory).